# Avoid rebuilding local dependency if it has already been built on its own

Tags: haskell, build, dependencies, haskell-stack

I have a local dependency in my `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-deps:
    - foo/bar
    - foo/quux
```

I also have a `stack.yaml` in `foo`:

```
packages:
    - bar
    - quux
```

Now let's suppose I do the following sequence of actions:

1. Change something in `foo/bar` or `foo/quux`
2. Do a `stack build` in `foo`
3. Do a `stack build` in the root directory

If #2 succeeds, I would expect #3 to not rebuild `foo/bar` or `foo/quux`, since step #2 already did that. However, it seems the build under `foo` is not reused for the build in `/` by default. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why not just _always_ only build in the root directory?

Comment: @leftaroundabout mostly because I hack around more under `foo` than the top-level, I run the `foo/*` tests only, I load `foo` files into the repl, and so on.